# Branching Processes of Binomial Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, statistical-inference, markov-process

Suppose that $Y_{n;k}\sim\text{Bin}(2,p)$, where $1/2<p<1$ is a branching process. What is the probability of extinction?

I know that to find the probability of extinction, we use the generating function as $\mathcal{P}_Y(q)$ where $q$ is the probability of extinction and $\mathcal{P}(t) = [(1-p) + tp]^2$. My problem is how to correctly solve this. I thought of this $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{X_1}Y_{n,k} = Y_{2,1} + Y_{2,X_{1}}$ but I don't how to proceed with this.

By definition $X_n = \sum_{k=1}^{X_{n-1}} Y_{n,k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $E[X_n] = m^n = (2p)^3 $ where $m = (2p) > 1$,  thus, $\pi_0 < 1.$ So we find $\pi_0.$
\begin{align*}
\pi_0 & =  \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \{\text{Population dies out $| X_1 = j$}\}\times p_j\\
& = \sum_{j=0}^{3} \pi_0^j \times p_j \\
0 &  = p^2\pi^2_0 + (2p-2p^2 - 1)\pi_0 + (1-p)^2
\end{align*}
This is a quadratic equation. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\pi_0 & = \frac{(2p^2-2p + 1) \pm \sqrt{4p^2 - 4p +1}}{2p^2}\\
& \text{since } p \in (1/2, 1), \text{we let } p = 0.7.\\
& = \frac{0.58\pm 0.4}{0.98}\\
& = (0.18367, 1)
\end{align*}
We observed that $\forall$ $ p \in (1/2,1)$, $\pi_0$ has the smallest possible solution for which $\pi_0 < 1$. Thus the required probability is $$\pi_0 = \frac{(2p^2-2p + 1) - \sqrt{4p^2 - 4p +1}}{2p^2}.$$

Comment: I appreciate your help